# How to change the (displayed) selected item on a disabled JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, java-7, jcombobox

I'd like to change the displayed selected item on a disabled `JComboBox` programmatically. I tried

- enabling it before invoking `setSelectedItem` and disabling it right after
- the former and invoking `updateUI` before disabling

It might be that this isn't intended, but would save me the work to replace the combobox with a `JLabel`, so a dirty hack answer would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Did you call `repaint()`?

Comment: @user268396 `setSelectedItem` is a bound property, that is, it will trigger a repaint on it's own. Most likely, the object the user is using with the `setSelectedItem` call is to `equal` to any of the values in the `JComboBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems to work okay for me...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{
                "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
            });
            cb.setEnabled(false);
            add(cb, gbc);
            cb.setEnabled(false);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Update");
            add(btn, gbc);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cb.setSelectedItem("Five");
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Make sure the object you using is `equal` to the value in the `JComboBox`